# how to best structure an app that receives data based on requests and has to handle the responses asynchronously

Tags: android, multithreading

I am working on an app that sends requests over WIFI and receives back (also sometimes delayed) an answer to that request.

While it is clear not to do the communication stuff in the UI thread I was wondering which scheme to use trying to understand the advantages/disadvantages in this situation.

The 3 threads would look like this:

1. UI
2. communicationManager (cM): managing which requests to be sent and interpreting the answers
3. communicationSenderAndReceiver (cSR): sending and receiving the messages so that the cM does not get blocked. It has an endless loop to receive any answers that might come in

As far as I know there are these possibilities between cM and cSR:

1. cM calls cSR.sendRequest to send requests. cM receives responses through its handler from cSR.  cSR reports to cM like this

   mHandler.obtainMessage(Main_screen.MESSAGE_KEY, data, -1)
               .sendToTarget();
2. cM calls cSR.sendRequest to send requests. cSR reports to cM like this

   cM.acceptResponse(data);

I am not sure which one to use or even where the difference is?

There is a nice comparison here http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html, but it really does not answer my question. All I know from there is I can not use AsyncTask since I need an endless receiver loop. And I cannot use services since they block the UI.

I hope I could make myself clear.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not write the cM to use a new instance of AsyncTask for each message? Basically, spawn a new one, that just waits for its response, and then when the response arrives, it notifies the cM that it's gotten its response, and processing continues?

Comment: The answers just come back (if at all) at any time, so it could be that cM sends R1, R2, R3 and only then A1 is returned. So the AsyncTasks could not really wait for THEIR response. That's why I need the endless receiver loop. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: How are you sending the reqeusts? My thought was that you would do it via something like http, so you could spawn a new AsyncTask that sends the request, and waits for the response; do this for each request you have to make, then they take care of themselves. 

Alternatively, if you're blasting messages out into the ether, and waiting to receive messages from the ether, then you've got to build something that handles the messages and sends them to their desired recipient. In this case, the messages are going to have to have an addressee so you know where to send it.

Comment: Yes it's the latter case - my question is about reporting back from cSR to cM via 1.mHandler.obtainMessage(Main_screen.MESSAGE_KEY, data, -1) .sendToTarget(); OR 2.cM.acceptResponse(data);  I really do not know the difference????

Comment: If you post some code, I could try to help out, I assumed you knew what these methods did - but I'll need some more context.

Comment: After one complete day of rewriting the communication the answer is: it makes a big difference. Using simple method communication between threads is a big mistake - it fills the callstack. One has to use the handler to avoid this! So whoever reads this will save himself lots of work!